# find Current running cypress command in cypress config

Tags: cypress, cypress-custom-commands

is there any way to **find the Current running cypress command** when it reaches the first time to the cypress config.ts file?

actually, **I need to do something based on the command** used by a user

example

**if the cypress command is executed to run specific test cases**

**I need to do some operation**

if the cypress command has some key in command I need to perform some operation

so is there any way to determine which cypress command the user entered while running the cypress

Answer (score 0):

No, not directly. The `cypress.config.ts` file is loaded and executed when Cypress starts, and any configuration values set there will not be available until after the configuration file has been processed.

You can include the operation inside the `before` \ `beforeEach` hook of the test spec files. If you need to run it every time (regardless of the test spec used), you can include the `before` \ `beforeEach` hook inside the `support/index.ts` file.

If the **operation** (sorry you didn't specify) is a non-Cypress command, then you can use `cy.task`.

Sample code:

```js
before(() => { // run this to generate data for the entire suite
    cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/data.json');
    cy.task('log', 'This will be output to the terminal');
});
```

Comment: partially useful answer thank you